# Having trouble in using sample code for registry key

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, registry

The sample code can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197002(v=vs.85).aspx

The code is about a third of the way down on the page, immediately underneath "Community Content" "IERegCreateKeyEx now working in c#, Please can you help with RegCloseKey"

Thanks for any help.  I've tried for several days to use this.  It compiles perfectly but I can't manage to call the public **SetRegValue** and **CreatRegKey** functions exposed in the public static class ProtectedModeHelper.

Any IE key value can be used in the sample; feel free to use your own in an example, e.g., `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Settings`.

Comment: That's not sample code. That's something that someone other than Microsoft posted. There is no reason to expect it to "work".

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you just need to create a registry key?

Comment: It's been confirmed by the author to work after he reposted it a day later (migrated to the top of the Community Content list).  Elsewhere on the web, http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_24853866.html it was confirmed with a handful of statement changes.

Comment: Fur, John, thank you both for responding.  I've been told that IECreateRegKeyEx(), inside that code, both opens and creates a key, depending on whether it's already extant.  I don't necessarily have to use the ieframe.dll that the sample code imports.  I do need to change the value of an existing IE key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are programming in C#, you could use the [RegistryKey class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) to perform such tasks. Below is a sample code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) showing how to create keys and set their values:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Create a subkey named Test9999 under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.
    RegistryKey test9999 = 
        Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Test9999");
    // Create two subkeys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test9999. The
    // keys are disposed when execution exits the using statement.
    using(RegistryKey 
        testName = test9999.CreateSubKey("TestName"),
        testSettings = test9999.CreateSubKey("TestSettings"))
    {
        // Create data for the TestSettings subkey.
        testSettings.SetValue("Language", "French");
        testSettings.SetValue("Level", "Intermediate");
        testSettings.SetValue("ID", 123);
    }
}
```

To modify an existing key you have to open it using the [RegistryKey.OpenSubKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d.aspx) specifying that you want write access to be applied to the key, then you can call [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kk9bxk9.aspx) like showed above.